# Accessing a child element in CSS

Tags: css

Here is the html list:

```
<aside id="polylang-3" class="widget widget_polylang cf">
    <ul> 
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-da"> danish </li>
    </ul>
<aside>
```

Now there is css applied to list items as following:

```
.widget > ul  > li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 0 8px 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eeeeee;
}
```

I would only like to access the above list, but cannot get to its items neither by id, nor by class.
Must be something simple, but I just cannot figure it out. 
Many thanks in advance.

Finally, have got it to work.
I could access it like the following:

```
#polylang-3.widget ul li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

The porblem was that I wanted to erase the border-bottom, but previously I did not set it to "none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to access it just by this

```
#polylang-3 li{
/*your css code*/
}
```

Comment: well I still cannot access it this way. I basically want to override the previously stated css block with a new one that would only apply to Polylang-3

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
.widget ul li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 0 8px 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: I want to access just the list which is in "aside" of id:polylang-3

Comment: pardon sir, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: this .wiget ul li{} will access any list of "widget" class, but I want to only access a list that is of "widget widget_polylang cf" class + with an id of "polylang-3"